# Local logs display

Tags: logging, kibana, local, free, splunk

I'm working on a little side project that has 3 microservices (running locally).
Each service write logs to a local file.
I was wondering if there's any free, local easy-to-setup tool that I can use in order to view the logs in a convenient way Instead of reading them in notepad++ (something like kibana or splunk but free and easy to setup).

Thanks!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use open source https://github.com/zinclabs/zincobserve . Its light weight that you run on your laptop. You will need to forward the logs using fluentbit or vector.

Answer (score 1):

Splunk is free to use for up to 500MB per day of logging.